# Django Rest Framework Extra kwargs fields for Password and Unique Email

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I tried creating serializers for my Model and tried serializing Model I want password field be typed in `****` format when I try entering password and Email to be unique from Extra kwargs fields how can I do that?
here is my serializers I tried.

```
   User = get_user_model()
    
    
    class AddBusCompanyUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        position = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=StaffPosition.objects.all())
    
        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = (
                'phone_number',
                'password',
                'position',
                'email',
            )
            extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True},'email':?}
}
```

what validator should I try making email being unique and password field being typed in **** format?

Comment: What do you mean by "unique by extra kwargs" ?

Comment: i want email to be passed unique `email': {'validators': []}` dont know what validator should i apply and password be typed in **** while password is typed

Comment: @BriseBalloches got unique email in this way `{'email':{'validators': [UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())]}`

Comment: not getting password in **** instead of 1234

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally worked on my own

```
 extra_kwargs = {
        'password': {
            'write_only': True,
            'style': {'input_type': 'password'}
        },
        'email': {
            'validators': [
                UniqueValidator(
                    queryset=User.objects.all()
                )
            ]
        }
    }
    'style': {'input_type': 'password'}
```

allows password to be in **** format in serializers and

```
'validators': [
                UniqueValidator(
                    queryset=User.objects.all()
                )
            ]
```

allows email to be unique